# sqlite alter using select and match from other tables

Tags: sqlite

I know how to do these sorts of things using perl, python or even MySQL but I can't not seem to figure out how to do this with sqlite.  Hoping maybe somebody here can help.

UPDATED NOTE: I'm limited to sqlite version 2.8.17

I have:

```
create table Ta (
    a1 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    a2 VARCHAR(12) );

create table Tb (
    b1 VARCHAR(12) PRIMARY KEY, 
    b2 INTEGER, 
    b3 VARCHAR(8), 
    b4 VARCHAR(8) );
```

What I would like to do via the command line and in a basic sql script is this:
Go through all of the rows in Tb and where b2 == a1, I would like to replace the value stored in b1 with the cooresponding value in a2.

Simplified it's something like:
    b1 = select a2 from Ta where a1 = b2

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
UPDATE Tb
    SET
        b1 = (SELECT a2 
              FROM Ta
              WHERE Tb.b2 = Ta.a1 )
    WHERE
        EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM Ta
            WHERE Tb.b2 = Ta.a1 );
```

Comment: Tried this earlier, there's problems with the SELECT statement in the second WHERE.  Also, it seems sqlite doesn't know how to handle things like Ta.a1

Answer (score 0):

Unless I missed something in your question, you simply have to update:

```
update tb set b1 = (select a2 from Ta where a1 = b2);
```

**UPDATE 1**

OP mentions that she/he is using sqlite 2.8.17, so "cross-table" updates are not supported.

I found this [link](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=UnsupportedSqlUpdateWithFrom) which provides a workaround. It requires that the field joined on be primary keys, which is the case for this question.

Here is the statement:

```
insert or replace into tb (b2, b1) 
select ta.a1, ta.a2 
from ta, tb 
where ta.a1=tb.b2;
```

I haven't tested it otherwise then verifying that it executes without errors. To the best of my SQL knowledge it should do the same as the update statement I posted prior to this update.

**UPDATE 2**

There is a problem with the above as the OP pointed out. It will insert new records rather than update existing records in Tb. I do now see a contradiction in what the OP is trying to do:

Assume that sqlite 3.x.y is used. A simple `update` statement can get the job done. The problem is that it will fail as soon as more than one record in `Tb` has the same `b2` value that exists in `Ta.a1`:

```
sqlite> create table ta (
   ...>     a_key INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   ...>     a_val TEXT);
sqlite> create table tb (
   ...>     b_key TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
   ...>     b_val INTEGER);
sqlite> insert into ta values (1, 'a');
sqlite> insert into tb values ('z', 1);
sqlite> insert into tb values ('y', 1);
sqlite> update tb set b_key=(select a_val from ta where a_key=b_val); 
Error: column b_key is not unique
```

So the solution here is to make `Tb1.b2` unique:

```
create table Tb (
    b1 VARCHAR(12) PRIMARY KEY, 
    b2 INTEGER UNIQUE, 
    b3 VARCHAR(8), 
    b4 VARCHAR(8));
```

Making `Tb.b2` unique makes the solution in my first update work properly and *prevents* the uniqueness violation exposed above.

Comment: That's what I thought... but sqlite gives an error: "no such column: b2".  It seems it's looking for it in Ta, and syntax like "Ta.b2" doesn't seem to work with sqlite.

Comment: 2.8.17, and I unfortunately can't update or move to something else.

Comment: Ha that's what I was missing ;-)

Comment: Sorry... should have mentioned that important detail :)

Comment: Hmmm.... that might work.  I have to say my sql skills aren't so hot.  Suggestions on how to do the inner join?

Comment: Most excellent, this solves the problem.  It needs a little tweaking as it currently appends the new columns to the table but I think I know how to resolve that.  Thank sixfeetsizx!!!!

Comment: So close... but sadly this only works for identical tables, and it seems that it will always insert new rows.